# Python Code Structure

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some Python 3.4 code I have written that does execute correctly but when using different IDE's to help me find errors I get a variable referenced before assignment error in this code snippet:

```
if os.path.isfile(o.options_file):  # Make sure this really is a file.
    options = (csv.reader(open(o.options_file), delimiter='\t'))
else:
    exit("Options_File Not Found.  Check File Name and Path.")
count = 0
for line in options:
    count += 1
```

It is the options variable that is throwing the error.  Can this be ignored or should I assign a Null value to options?

Comment: A code checker should give you an ignorable warning here, not an error.  A false error claim is an error.  On the other hand, Martijn's 'bail first on error' solution is a pretty good practice in general..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just invert the test:

```
if not os.path.isfile(o.options_file):  # Make sure this really is a file.
    exit("Options_File Not Found.  Check File Name and Path.")

options = (csv.reader(open(o.options_file), delimiter='\t'))
count = 0
for line in options:
    count += 1
```

This makes it far clearer, both to code linting tools *and* other developers, that the rest of the code won't run if the file doesn't exist.